# Have two Home Folders

Tags: gnome

Have just installed 11.10 and Gnome Shell 3.2 in the past few days and noticed I have two Home folders, one "home" the other "Home" (upper case H). They both have the same folders and files in and if I delete a file from one it is also deleted from the other.
I cannot delete either and would welcome any guidance you can give.[image: copy of desktop]

Thank you.
John Billot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is completely fine.

`home` is the home directory for all users.

`Home` is a simpler way to see your own directory, and is only used in the File Browser

In the screenshot, I've changed to the Tree View (*View* Menu -> Sidebar -> Tree), and the Home at the top is just a quick link to my home directory (which is infact `/home/nemo`).

Similarly user temp has his home directory at `/home/temp`. If I were to login as temp, `Home` would take me to `/home/temp`, but show `Home` at the address bar.

[image: Screenshot]

In an analogy to *Windows 7*, the `/home` directory equates to `C:\Users`, where different User folders are present.

Comment: Thank you for that. I don't recall having this on any previous version although I've not had any other "user" including "guest" before. Thanks once again.